# LDAP Python Query differing results from built in linux tool ldapquery

Tags: python, linux, ldap

I'm having issues retrieving all attributes from a LDAP server using a python ldap script.

First off, what I can pull using the linux command `ldapsearch`

If I run `ldapsearch -LLL uid=user` and do not specify the host that I want to hit, I do not get back all of the attributes I want.

HOWEVER, if I run `ldapsearch -LLL -h ldaphost uid=user` I get back ALL of the attributes that are available. I'm chalking this up to one LDAP server having more attributes that I need.

Anyway, back to my python script...here's the script I'm executing:

```
    # Initialize and bind
con = ldap.initialize('ldaphost')

con.simple_bind_s()

# Run a query against the directory
baseDN = "basedn"
searchScope = ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE
retrieveAttributes = None
searchFilter = uid=user

res = con.search_s(baseDN, searchScope, searchFilter, retrieveAttributes)
print res
```

When I run this python script, the output is the exact same list of attributes that I achieved when I execute `ldapsearch -LLL uid=user`...it's almost like my python script is not actually connecting to the desired host and pulling the extra attributes that only that LDAP host will give me.

Is there an additional piece that I need to add to this script to specify a LDAP host? It seems like I am doing that in the second line of the script, but I'm not a LDAP guru and am probably doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think we need to compare what the first `ldapsearch` is doing, where you don't specify the ldap server. It should be checking in `/etc/ldap.conf` or `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` (depends on your Linux distribution). It may be that the LDAP server responds differently over SSL or TLS, or something else, but I'd start by comparing the connection details that way

Comment: I'm assuming that `searchFilter = uid=user` is actually `searchFilter = "uid=user"` with quotes, btw.

Comment: Correct, thank you for that modification. I was actually passing that variable from the command line, so to simplify the script in this question, I just put it in the function, but failed on the correct syntax.

Comment: It turns out that the reason that I'm getting extra attributes when I use ldapsearch is because it is kerberized and thus uses my kerberos ticket that I'm granted when I log into the server I'm running the command from....which apparently the python script is not. I will need to check and see if Python can pull in a Kerberos ticket and use that for the LDAP query? Not sure....